# matplotlib 1.5 cannot align grid lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I recently upgraded to `matplotlib` v1.5. What I started seeing is that `twinx` plots started to **fail to align grid lines** even when I manually sets the yaxis ticks.

I'm using Anaconda v.2.4 with Python 2.7.

**EDIT: 2015-11-25, as suggested by @ali_m, I submitted an ticket about this [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5560) on GitHub.**

E.g:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

x = [x + 0.5 for x in range(10)]
z = [(y+0.0)/10-0.004 for y in range(10)]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': x})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'z': z})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# plot something with ax
df1.plot(ax=ax)

# plot second dataframe on secondary y
ax2 = ax.twinx()
df2.plot(ax=ax2)

print('Before setting ax ticks (not ax2)')
print('ax ticks', ax.get_yticks())
print('ax2 ticks', ax2.get_yticks())
print('ax2 ybound', ax2.get_ybound())

# manually set the number of ticks for both axes to match 
ticks = ax.get_yticks()
dis = ticks[-1] - ticks[-2]
# left axis has less ticks then right by default
for _ in range(len(ax2.get_yticks()) - len(ax.get_yticks())):
    ticks = np.append(ticks, ticks[-1] + dis)
# print('ticks', ticks)
# comment out this line below to NOT set ticks
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(ticks)

print('After setting ax ticks (not ax2)')
print('ax ticks', ax.get_yticks())
print('ax2 ticks', ax2.get_yticks())
print('ax2 ybound', ax2.get_ybound())
```

OUTPUT:

```
# you can see here that the number of ticks matched for both axes.

Before setting ticks
ax ticks [  0.   2.   4.   6.   8.  10.]
ax ybound (0.0, 10.0)
ax2 ticks [-0.2  0.   0.2  0.4  0.6  0.8  1.   1.2]
ax2 ybound (-0.20000000000000001, 1.0000000000000002)
After setting ticks
ax ticks [  0.   2.   4.   6.   8.  10.  12.  14.]
ax ybound (0.0, 14.0)
ax2 ticks [-0.2  0.   0.2  0.4  0.6  0.8  1.   1.2]
ax2 ybound (-0.20000000000000001, 1.0000000000000002)
```

However, when in the plot, the right axis `ax2`'s last tick is not show, i.e. **the maximum stops at `1.0`, rather than `1.2` as show in the print out above.**

**EDIT - Note that I manually set ticks for `ax`, not `ax2`, the problem is happening to `ax2`.**
[image]

**Question 1: why is the last tick not show on the right axis?**

**EDIT**: Thanks to @DilithiumMatrix & @ali_m, I now see that setting ticks doesn't update limits or bounds. However, this problem is happening to the right axis, whose limits and bounds are set automatically through `df2.plot(ax=ax2)`. **Perhaps someone can comment on how the logic to set limits & bounds work automatically?**

**Question 2: Any suggestions on how I can get the grid lines to match again?**

**EDIT** I figured out a hack by manually setting the upper `ybound`, it re-aligns the grid lines...

```
ax.set_ybound(upper=max(ax.get_yticks()))
ax2.set_ybound(upper=max(ax2.get_yticks()))
```

In fact I just tried to plot these **WITHOUT** manually setting the ticks you still get the same problem.

EDIT: Adding a pic to show default `ax2` behaviour, without changing `ax`'s ticks.

[image: Default <code>ax2</code> behaviour still does not show 1.2 tick]

Comment: This behavior is not specific to matplotlib v1.5.0 - I see the same thing in v1.4.2. Although the secondary y-axis appears to behave inconsistently with respect to the primary, I'm not sure whether this can be regarded as a bug, since the rescaling of axis limits by `ax.set_yticks` does not seem to be documented anywhere. The documented methods for changing the axis limits are `ax.set_ylim` and `ax.set_ybound`, which behave as expected for the secondary y-axis.

Comment: Grid lines are **not supposed** to be aligned on different axes.

Comment: @ali_m Possibly, however, the even without calling `ax.set_yticks`, `ax2` already experiences this problem. Added code to show that.

Comment: @ali_m `ax` has less ticks than `ax2`, so i'm increase its no. of ticks to match `ax2`'s. I do manually set the axis limits for `ax`. The problem is with `ax2` - its default upper ybound is 1.0, but shouldn't it be 1.2 instead (`np.max(ax2.get_yticks())`?

Comment: *Why* do you expect its upper bound to be 1.2 when you haven't done anything to set it that way?

Comment: @ali_m I'm assuming that it should be smart enough to figure out that the bound should be the max of ticks by default. So it looks like that's not the case? Seems to be inconsistent, no?

Comment: As I said above, it might be inconsistent behaviour, but on the other hand it seems very unsafe to assume that setting the tick locations *should* change the axis limits, since there doesn't seem to be anything in the documentation to suggest that this should happen.

Comment: @ali_m I see what you mean now. I agree, it's not a bug, but probably a feature worth having. I wonder how limits are inferred from data - since this is set automatically here with `ax2`, not manually set like `ax`.

Comment: Never rely on undocumented features! By all means go post on the [matplotlib issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues) - at the very least it would be good to have some clarification on the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this behavior would just start with matplotlib v1.5, as aligning the grid lines for different axes has never been a feature (to my knowledge).  It seems as though the issue you're having, however, is setting the y *limits*.  Calling `set_yticks` (which internal calls the `yaxis.set_ticks` method), does **not** set the limits --- it just sets the 'locator' of the ticks.  If you want to set the bounds of the axis, you need to call one of those methods explicitly, in this case either `ax.set_ylim` or `ax.set_ybound`.

Addition:
Tick marks are always really weird / difficult to mess-with.  The way I tend to do things these days is to always deal with them very explicitly.  Set the limits to particular values, set the ticks to particular values.  Don't count on the default-defined tick-marks to be what you would naively expect.

Comment: Hi - The problem here is that, actually I manually set the ticks for the LEFT axis `ax`, whereas the display problem is happening for the RIGHT axis `ax2`. I can see why there could be a need to call `ax.set_ybound()` (although it didn't seem needed), but this is happening to the axis I have **not** touched... Fully understand that aligning grid lines are not supported, I had a function which did that, but it was broken after upgrading to 1.5... Thanks

Comment: @WillZhang I don't understand how that's relevant.  If you want explicit bounds for an axis, you have to set them.

Comment: So the real question is why `np.max(ax2.get_yticks())` is 1.2 but in the chart `ax` is only bounded at 1.0? Shouldn't the default be 1.2 with `df2.plot(ax=ax2)`?

Comment: @WillZhang I'm just guessing, but probably because the limits ended up being adjusted at draw time (e.g.) while the ticks were set at a different time... Messing with tick-marks is always tricky.  Editted answer with a general suggestion.